# Backbone Dropdown list empty after `.fetch()` on collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

We are using ASP.Net MVC 4 and have a JSONResult Method called `GetDistricts` that outputs the result below. The issue I am having is that when I manually go to the url `/Home/GetDistricts` I get the result below, but the Backbone collection is not filled with data when it calls `fetch()`. I have placed a breakpoint on the spot in the code where it is called and verified that `this.districts` is an empty array. Also in the Network tab in Chrome's inspector, the AJAX call to the method is successful (200) but has an empty response. Again going there manually does produce a result. Also I have ensured to set `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`.

Why am I not getting the JSON result back?

**Backbone:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //Model
        District = Backbone.Model.extend({
            idAttribute: 'DistrictKey',
            defaults: {
                DistrictKey: 0,
                DistrictName: null
            }
        });

        //Collection
        Districts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: District,
            url: "/Home/GetDistricts"
        });

        //View
        DistrictDropdown = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $("#district-dropdown"),
            initialize: function() {
                this.districts = new Districts;
                this.districts.fetch();
                this.render();
            },
            render: function() {
                this.$el.html(_.template($("#district-dropdown-template").html(), {districts: this.districts }));
                return this;
            },
            events: {
                "change #district-dropdown-control": "loadSchools",
            },
            loadSchools: function() {
                //Do work
            }
        });

        //Create the view
        var districtDropdown = new DistrictDropdown;
    });
</script>
```

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="district-dropdown-template">
    <select id="district-dropdown-control" name="districts">
        <% districts.each(function (district) { %>
            <option value="<%= district.get('DistrictKey') %>"><%= district.get('DistrictName') %></option>
        <% }); %>
    </select>
</script>
```

**JSON Return from /Home/GetDistricts:**

```
[
    {
        "DistrictKey": 1,
        "DistrictName": "District A"
    },
    {
        "DistrictKey": 2,
        "DistrictName": "District B"
    },
    {
        "DistrictKey": 3,
        "DistrictName": "District C"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your render method is being called before the fetch method retrieved the data from the server.

Use the callback:

```
fetch({
    success: function() {
            // call render
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I do that and still keep the correct context of `this`?

Comment: You could always do the old var that = this; before the callback. then that.render();